# Glue an image to the previous paragraph

Tags: luatex

I have a document that is generated more or less automatically. I have a macro which glues the section header to the subtitle. I can somehow prevent that the macro (=section header with its subtitle) is the last on the page - if some text follows. To do this, I use the `needspace` package with the `needspace{3\baselineskip}` option. This works quite well.

The new challenge I'm facing is an image that follows the macro. Generally, an image should be placed where it appears - for which I use the `float` package. The problem is that there can be a page break between the subtitle and the image. The title won't appear on the same page as the image.

In general: I want to glue the image to the macro without an additional page break. My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float} 
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow} 
\usepackage{needspace} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-3]
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}
    % START: Macro for the subtitle for glueing the subtitle to the title
    \section{This is a section}
    % glue the subtitle to the section 
    \nopagebreak\endgraf\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
       \small{\textcolor{violet}{With a subtitle for the section.}}
    }\endgraf\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    % END: Macro for the subtitle for glueing the subtitle to the title
    %prevent page-break???
    \begin{figure}
        \rule{2cm}{10cm}.
    \end{figure}
    \kant[9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, if I have formulated it wrong. The images are NOT "essentially part of the section heading". The images MIGHT appear after the section headings - but generally a regular text is inserted and an image is somewhere in the text. Just once in a while an image is directly after the section headers and for this scenario I'm looking for an approach.